# Creating Flash CS5 project from Flex project

Tags: apache-flex, project, flash-cs5

I recieved a Flex project and I want to try to compile and run it using Adobe Flash Professional, but I unable to do it. How can I do it?

I think that I need to create a new project and import every single class from Flex project to a new project in Adobe Flash Professional. Can someone help me?

Comment: Why would you even want to do that? Flex uses mxml, which Flash Builder does not compile. Flash Builder uses the free Flex SDK to compile, so you can download the sdk and compile the project from the commandline

Comment: @Pranav Hosangadi Flash Builder should have no problems compiling MXML.  Did you mean to say that Flash Professional will not compile MXML?

Comment: Ah, my bad.. I meant to say Flash Professional... :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really, I strongly recommend against even trying, because it is going to be tediously hard.  The Flex Compiler does a lot of framework setup behind the scenes, and you'd have to re-write all that code manually to get a Flex project to compile / work in Flash CS5.  This will be extra difficult if any MXML is used in the Flex project, which is likely.

That said, a few people have experimented with that stuff.  [This is the best one, on manually initializing the SystemManager](http://guyinthechair.com/?p=113).

This one came up in Google search and may be [useful too](http://actionscriptexamples.com/2008/10/26/using-the-flex-sdk-with-flash-cs4/).